# My fresh React App is blank on the webpage

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am brand new to react. I installed it on my work computer and the first compile worked fine and it showed on the local host just fine and had the cool react logo spinning. I decided to install it on my home PC and run it, compiles fine in the terminal but the webpage that shows up is blank. I haven't changed anything in the files.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Edit: OS Windows, Node.js Version 13.8.0, npm version 6.13.6, npx 6.13.6, Browser Google Chrome

Comment: This isn't something we can help you with without more information. OS the same? node.js versions the same? Same package versions? Same browser? There's many factors

Comment: Check your browser's JavaScript console for errors.

Comment: edited versions asked for in :) also how do I find the console on chrome?

Comment: Tools > Web Developer > Web Console. You're **really** going to want to get familiar with the various bits of the console before you do much JS development.